# Unable to scroll (broken TextBox) after Select and ChangeView in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I just want to scroll to my regex result.
I notice that if I only use Select or only ChangeView , there is no error
(but no result too).

```
private void showrez()
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                ContentBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                ContentBox.Select(head.Index, head.Length);
                var r = ContentBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(ContentBox.SelectionStart, false);

                var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ContentBox, 0);
                for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid); i++)
                {
                    object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
                    if (obj is ScrollViewer)
                    {
                        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(r.Left, r.Top, null);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

I just checked this works without bugs , but used methods are obsolete.

```
private void showrez()
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                ContentBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                ContentBox.Select(head.Index, head.Length);
                var r = ContentBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(ContentBox.SelectionStart, false);

                var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ContentBox, 0);
                for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid); i++)
                {
                    object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
                    if (obj is ScrollViewer)
                    {
                        //((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(r.Left, r.Top, null);

                        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ScrollToVerticalOffset(r.Top);
                        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ScrollToHorizontalOffset(r.Left);

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use the [`ChangeView(IReference<Double>, IReference<Double>, IReference<Single>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ChangeView_Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Single__) method it enable scrolling animation by default. 
Please try to use the [`ChangeView(IReference<Double>, IReference<Double>, IReference<Single>, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ChangeView_Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Single__System_Boolean_) and we should be able to set true to disable zoom/pan animations while changing the view. The default is false.

Foe example:

```
((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(r.Left, r.Top, null,true);
```